# How do I set up a graphical Form indicator in terms of "Won, Lost, Drawn" in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I would like to display a players' form in my app, something like this:

[image]

My current code stands at this:

```
class CommunityLeagueStatsVC: UIViewController {

struct Form {
    var player1_results: String?

    init(_ dictionary: [String : String]) {
        self.player1_results = dictionary["player1_result"]

    }
}

var leagueForm = [Form]()

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    let myUrl = URL(string: "http://www.xyz.uk/xyz/getLeagueStats.php")
    var request = URLRequest(url:myUrl!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    let postString = "player_id=\(self.playerId2!)&community_id=\(communityId2!)";

    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async
            {
                do{

                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String:AnyObject]
                    print (json!)

                    if let dict = json?["leagueStats"] as? [String:AnyObject] {

                        if let arr = dict["player1Form"] as? [[String:String]] {


                            self.leagueForm = arr.flatMap { Form($0) }
                            print (self.leagueForm)
                        }
          }
  }
```

This `print (self.leagueForm)` outputs my dictionary as:

> [KeepScore.CommunityLeagueStatsVC.Form(player1_results: Optional("D")), KeepScore.CommunityLeagueStatsVC.Form(player1_results: Optional("W")), KeepScore.CommunityLeagueStatsVC.Form(player1_results: Optional("L")), KeepScore.CommunityLeagueStatsVC.Form(player1_results: Optional("W")), KeepScore.CommunityLeagueStatsVC.Form(player1_results: Optional("W")), KeepScore.CommunityLeagueStatsVC.Form(player1_results: Optional("W")), KeepScore.CommunityLeagueStatsVC.Form(player1_results: Optional("D")), KeepScore.CommunityLeagueStatsVC.Form(player1_results: Optional("W"))]

In my thinking I could print a list of the retrieved data such as "WDWWWLWW" but ideally I would replace each of these letters with a corresponding coloured square as in the image shown above.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: what do you mean by 'print a list'?  print to a debugger / lo, or are you displaying somewhere on screen where you can use some kind of UIView?

Comment: I am thinking I would print to a View Object, just iterate through and print the string of each next to each other.  Obviously this would look terrible.  But then maybe I could do a string match?

Comment: You could create a custom control, based on UIView, initialise it with your results, and then draw exactly what you have as the example

Comment: as an aside - xxx.com is probably NOT the best way to anonymise your url!

Comment: haha! noted! Thanks I'll look into custom controls - not used them before (as far as I'm aware)

Comment: Do not use mere colored dashes. Some of us can't see those colors. I thought it was just a uniform row of dashes until I read the end of your question!

Comment: It is very easy to "translate" the string WDWWWLWW into a row of eight symbols. What's the hard part for you?

Comment: @matt I'm just new to Swift.  This is my first app, and pretty much the final thing I need to do, and its just up until now its not a technique i've had to use so not learned how to do it yet.  Noted about the colours...

Comment: There are many good tutorials available - try this one https://www.raywenderlich.com/76433/how-to-make-a-custom-control-swift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Here's an example with custom controls
```

[image]

This is just using dummy data, with a couple of buttons to set  the values.

You can create a ResultsDisplay class like this

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class ResultsDisplay: UIImageView
{
    // default values - but they will be overwritten
    var colourWin       = UIColor.green
    var colourLose      = UIColor.red
    var colourDraw      = UIColor.gray
    var colourUnknown   = UIColor.blue

    var results : [String] = ["U", "U", "U", "U", "U", "U", "U", "U", "U", "U"]

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
    {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    func displayResults()
    {
        let displaySize = self.frame.size
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(displaySize, false, 0)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

        // draw line around the box
        context!.setLineWidth(1)
        context!.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
        context!.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: displaySize.width, y: 0))
        context!.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: displaySize.width, y: displaySize.height))
        context!.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: displaySize.height))
        context!.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
        context!.strokePath()

        let barGap      = CGFloat(10)
        let lineWidth   = CGFloat(5)
        let lineLength  = (displaySize.width - barGap * 11) / 10

        context!.setLineWidth(lineWidth)

        for (index, result) in results.enumerated()
        {
            switch result
            {
                case "W":
                    context!.setStrokeColor(colourWin.cgColor)
                case "L":
                    context!.setStrokeColor(colourLose.cgColor)
                case "D":
                    context!.setStrokeColor(colourDraw.cgColor)
                default:
                    context!.setStrokeColor(colourUnknown.cgColor)
            }
            let x = barGap + CGFloat(index) * (lineLength + barGap)

            context!.move(to: CGPoint(x: x, y: displaySize.height / 2))
            context!.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: x + lineLength, y: displaySize.height / 2))
            context!.strokePath()
        }
        self.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    }
}
```

then all you have to do is position a UIImageView where you want it, set the class to ResultsDisplay, and call `resultsDisplay.displayresults()'

With no data defined, it will show 10 blue lines (unknown), and after you set the results, it will draw as required.

As others have pointed out, you need more than colours to distinguish state - so instead of lines you could draw shapes, or include W / D/ L

In a more complete implementation, you need to sort out how you store the data - I have shown a simple version - and you would probably want to indlue the player name in the same display.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for your time in writing that out, I have all the blue lines appearing so going to try and take my data and update it with live info. Cheers @Russell

Comment: cool.  Happy to help.  When you get into the Custom Controls, you will see that you can customise the control a lot, with things like the colours becoming configurable in the Storyboard.  All good stuff

Comment: I have now arranged my live data into `self.formGuide` which is a var in my CommunityLeagueStatsVC class and outputs correctly as ["L", "L", "D", "W", "L", "W", "W", "W"].  So all I need to do is call this variable from the ResultsDisplay class / update `results' with this new data.  How do I call this?

Comment: Shall we go to a chat room?  I have one set up called `Swift Questions (Russell)`

Comment: I have put the sample project on github - https://github.com/CarterMiller/ResultsDisplay